# How to have no splitview in portrait mode in android?

Tags: android

I was able to create a split view using fragments in landscape mode to maximize the space. So for example, I can search on the left pane and it will show the detailed view on the right pane.

If the user switches to portrait mode during application usage, how can it be implemented in such a way that it is no longer in split view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has this exact example in their [code.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Example) You can specify a different layout dependent on the screen orientation. In the code you can perform a check to see what the current orientation is.